# How can I assign value to the struct inside union here?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, struct, unions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;

union ipv4 {
    struct bytes{
        uint8_t a;
        uint8_t b;
        uint8_t c;
        uint8_t d;
    } bytes;
    uint32_t int32;
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    union ipv4 addr;
    addr.bytes = { 192, 168, 0, 96 };
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d - (%08x)\n",
            addr.bytes.a, addr.bytes.b, addr.bytes.c, addr.bytes.d,
            addr.int32);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Error: c:\users\yayun.xie\documents\satmap\c++onlinematerial\exercise     files\chap05\union.cpp(18): error C2059: syntax error : '{';**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export structure declaration out of union, you can write you code like this (this fragment uses compound-literals which is C99's feature C++ forbids)

```
struct bytes_t {
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint8_t d;
};

union ipv4 {
    bytes_t bytes;
    uint32_t int32;
};
....
    addr.bytes = (bytes_t){ 192, 168, 0, 96 };
```

Or, alternatively you can assign fields one by one.

```
addr.bytes.a = 192;
addr.bytes.b = 168;
addr.bytes.c = 0;
addr.bytes.d = 96;
```

Or, all in once with declaration-initialization

```
ipv4 addr = { .bytes = { 192, 168, 0, 96 } };
```

`bytes` is first field of union, so you can drop out `.bytes =` and write just

```
ipv4 addr = { { 192, 168, 0, 96 } };
```

With C++11's extended initializer lists, this is also valid:

```
addr.bytes = { 192, 168, 0, 96 };
```

By the way, you forgot to include `stdio.h` to use `printf()` and `getchar()`.

Comment: addr.bytes = (bytes_t){ 192, 168, 0, 96 };  Doesn't work with MSVC 2010.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, Rasen.

Comment: All these samples are valid in both g++ and clang and compiles without any warning. If first of them is not valid for MSVC, try another one.

Comment: addr.bytes.a = 192;
addr.bytes.b = 168;
addr.bytes.c = 0;
addr.bytes.d = 96;

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use structure initialization in an assignment operation (`addr.bytes = ...`) prior to C++11. That's why the original code failed to compile, and why assigning the individual fields instead works fine.

Comment: I've stated C++11 variant separately. All the others should work as expected, except first one. First uses compound-literals, and I found that this is C99's feature which C++ forbids.